# Retrieving Publication Lists

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, publicationlist

I'm trying to retrieve Publication Lists from a child BU. Here's what I have:

```
var @rr, @sfp, @lists, @status
SET @rr = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
SetObjectProperty(@rr,"ObjectType","List")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","ID")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","List.ListName")

SET @sfp = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@sfp,"Property","Type")
SetObjectProperty(@sfp,"SimpleOperator","equals")
AddObjectArrayItem(@sfp,"Value","Public")

SetObjectProperty(@rr,"Filter",@sfp)

SET @lists = InvokeRetrieve(@rr, @status)
```

I can do this with a SOAP request using ClientID:

```
<RetrieveRequest>
    <ClientIDs>
        <ID>xxxxxxx</ID>
    </ClientIDs>            
    <ObjectType>List</ObjectType>
    <Properties>ID</Properties>
    <Properties>List.ListName</Properties>
    <Properties>List.Type</Properties>
    <Properties>List.Category</Properties>
    <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
    <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
        <Property>List.Type</Property>
        <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
        <Value>Public</Value>
    </Filter>
```

How would I specify the Client ID in AMPScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"ClientIDs" is an array, so you need to set it with AddObjectArrayItem() not SetObjectProperty()

```
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr, "ClientIDs", @client)
```

Answer (score 1):

At some point in your, you need to create a ClientID object to do what you're asking, like so:

```
SET @client = CreateObject("ClientID")
SetObjectProperty(@client, "ID", @memberID) /* @memberID is a placeholder for your MID /*
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I got the ClientID object created, but when I try to add it to the RetrieveRequest using  
  
 SETOBJECTPROPERTY(@rr, "ClientIDs", @client)  
  
 I get the following error:  
 Object of type 'ExactTarget.Integration.WSDL.ClientID' cannot be converted to type 'ExactTarget.Integration.WSDL.ClientID[]'.